# How do I represent range of integers dataype in C# from a JSON file?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to represent a C# object that serializes a GenBank-like JSON file that can look like this:

```
"id": "i14",
  "type": "mat_peptide",
  "range": [ 13025, 13441 ],
  "note": "nsp10_CysHis; formerly known as growth-factor-like protein (GFL); produced by both pp1a and pp1ab",
  "product": "nsp10",
  "protein_id": "YP_009725306.1",
  "gene": "ORF1ab",
  "locus_tag": "GU280_gp01"
```

or else

```
"id": "i15",
  "type": "mat_peptide",
  "range": {
    "join": [
      [ 13442, 13468 ],
      [ 13468, 16236 ]
    ]
  },
  "note": "nsp12; NiRAN and RdRp; produced by pp1ab only",
  "product": "RNA-dependent RNA polymerase",
  "protein_id": "YP_009725307.1",
  "gene": "ORF1ab",
  "locus_tag": "GU280_gp01"
```

And i'm looking for a datatype in C# that represents **"range"** in both ways (with or without **"join"**). Is there a way I could do that?

Comment: An Array that starts from 13442 to 16236 form example? If i wanted to deserialize that JSON will It be able to read It?

Comment: At the most basic level, a ``List<(int, int)>`` might do the trick for representing a list of ranges from one integer to another. The first form can easily be transformed into the second, that way you have a uniform representation which means less work when deserializing.

Answer (score 1):

You can Create a class call range to handle it

```
public class Range 
{
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }

    public Range(int min,int max)
    {
        (this.Min, this.Max) = (min, max);
    }
}
```

And deserialize with following syntax

```
var stringRanges = JObject.Parse(contents)["range"]["join"].Children();
List<Range> ranges = stringRanges.Select(c=>c.ToObject<int[]>())
                                 .Select(c=> new Range(c[0],c[1])).ToList();
```

Or if you dont want to create class

```
List<(int,int)> ranges = stringRanges.Select(c=>c.ToObject<int[]>())
                                     .Select(c=>(c[0],c[1])).ToList();
```

Hope it helps